# issues with connect function

Tags: c, sockets

I'm trying to get started on socket programming in C, and I was following a few guides, but I'm always getting this error:

```
warning: 

passing argument 2 of ‘connect’ from incompatible pointer type [-Wincompatible-pointer-types]
   45 | int status= connect(socket_desc , (struct sockaddr *) &server , sizeof(server));
      |                                   ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
      |                                   |
      |                                   struct sockaddr *
```

It wants `struct sockaddr *` to be constant, but when I try to make it constant, the `connect()` function doesn't have enough arguments.

```c
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <sys/socket.h>
#include <netinet/in.h>

int main (){

    int netsocket;
    netsocket = socket(AF_INET, SOCK_STREAM, 0);

    struct sockaddr_in server;
    server.sin_family = AF_INET;
    server.sin_port   = htons(9002); 
    server.sin_addr.s_addr   = INADDR_ANY;

    int Verbindungsstatus = connect(netsocket, (struct sockaddr *) &server, sizeof(server));
    if (Verbindungsstatus == -1){
        printf("Connection error");
    }
    printf("Connected!");
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: I cannot reproduce this error. Your code compiles without warnings: https://godbolt.org/z/qvjKTd7En

Comment: @NoBrain03, try casting as `const struct sockaddr *` instead of `struct sockaddr *`.

Comment: Do you have to compile Socket Programs different compared to regular c ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From the man page:

```
int connect(int sockfd, const struct sockaddr *addr,
                   socklen_t addrlen);
```

The second argument expects a `const struct sockaddr *addr`.

Perhaps try casting to `(const struct sockaddr *)` instead of `(struct sockaddr *)`.

New code should use `getaddrinfo()` instead of manually filling the `struct`. See the man page for an example:

https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/getaddrinfo.3.html

*Aside:* `socket()` may fail:

```c
netsocket = socket(AF_INET, SOCK_STREAM, 0);
```

Check its return value.

```c
errno = 0;
if ((netsocket = socket(AF_INET, SOCK_STREAM, 0)) == -1) {
    perror("socket");
}
```

Comment: OK it runs now. the issue was not code related. I somehow had two different files with the same name and the wrong one got compiled everytime

Comment: @Haris "*Perhaps try casting to `(const struct sockaddr *)` instead of `(struct sockaddr *)`*" - FYI, any non-const variable can be assigned to a `const` variable of the same type. The compiler will handle the conversion to `const` implicitly for you. Casting `&server` to `struct sockaddr*` is perfectly fine and expected, and assigning a `struct sockaddr*` to a `const struct sockaddr*` is perfectly fine.  So, adding the `const` to the cast is useless, especially since `server` is not `const` to begin with.

Comment: @Remy Indeed, that's why I said *perhaps*. Though, GCC does complain about implicit conversions when compiled with enough warnings. And strictly speaking, the code invokes undefined behaviour because it breaks the strict aliasing rule.

Comment: @Haris "*the code invokes undefined behaviour because it breaks the strict aliasing rule*" - in C++, definately. Not in C, though, where it is much less strict. Though, in the case of networking APIs, it is common/legacy enough to be generally safe as long as you stick to the API correctly: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67782621/